# Is it possible to reduce a JPEG image's file size by reducing its dimensions?

Tags: c#, jpeg

If there is a JPEG image with dimensions 800x600 and I want to reduce its file size by reducing its dimensions to, say, 768x576, how would I go about it?

Using the GDI+ library in .NET, I would have thought that by just opening the image, copying it to another with the desired dimensions and a quality setting of 100, the resulting image would have the same quality and would be automatically smaller (in bytes), because its dimensions are smaller than the original, but in my tests this doesn't seem to be the case. In fact, the size of the resulting image is larger than the original: from ~70K to ~280K.

So, is there any way this can be done? The final goal is to reduce the image size. I have also tried to save the image with the same dimensions and a quality setting of 70 or even 50, but I don't want to do that because it's impossible to determine if the original image has already been compressed to a point where saving it with such low settings will produce too much quality loss.

Comment: Is your actual question "how to determine compression level of JPEG with C#"? (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324790)

Comment: No... I stumbled upon that article during my research too, but the last bit about applications using custom tables and not being able to _always_ determine the quality setting using this method, made me discard it.

Answer (score 1):

You shoudn't save the file with a quality setting of 100. What you are doing is like taking a 128 kbps mp3 file and saving it at 192 kbps. You get a larger file with the same information in it, and you are probably losing some data just by decoding and encoding again.

I would start by keeping the image size and finding the quality at which you get the same file size. After that you can play around with the size and quality until you get your desired file size.

Comment: In addition to quality and pixel dimensions, note that the file size is affected by JPEG subsampling (4:1:1, 4:2:2 or 4:4:4), which you cannot control using GDI+. For more details, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954863/how-do-you-save-a-jpeg-with-4-2-2-and-high-quality-in-net)